# Selenium don't recognize driver with jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

When I execute the jenkins job, the selenium test always fail with this error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property
```

or when I set the driver path

```
not found /var/jenkins/.../C:/selenium/drivers/chromedrive
```

I have the follow environment

- 1 jenkins server and selenium hub running on linux
- 1 selenium node running on Windows.

The selenium node is running with the follow line

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:/selenium/drivers/chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar -port 5556 -role node -hub http://192.168.15.99:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=chrome, version=ANY, maxInstances=10, platform=WINDOWS"
```

Selenium hub and node can see each other.

[image: Selenium GRID console]

Why I can't execute the tests? Look's like selenium are trying to execute on the hub, not on the node. How can I configure to do not ask for Chrome driver location?

My test

```
public class TesteSelenium{

    private static final String APLICATION_CONTEXT = "/SYSA";
    WebDriver driver;
    HomePage home;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
            Properties p = PropertiesUtil.getProperties();
            File file = new File(p.getProperty("webdriver.path"));
            System.setProperty(p.getProperty("webdriver.type"), file.getAbsolutePath());

            driver = new ChromeDriver();
                             driver.get(p.getProperty("host.address")+APLICATION_CONTEXT);

            LoginPage login = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
            login.setUsuarioTextField(p.getProperty("usuario.selenium.login"));
            login.setSenhaPasswordField(p.getProperty("usuario.selenium.password"));
            home = login.submit();
    }       

    @After
    public void finish() {
            driver.close();
    }
```

I use a properties file

```
host.address = http://jbossserver:8080
usuario.selenium.login = USER_SELENIUM
usuario.selenium.password = 123123
webdriver.path = C:/selenium/drivers/chromedriver
webdriver.type = webdriver.chrome.driver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code to run Selenium tests remotely is slightly different.

```java
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
                Properties p = PropertiesUtil.getProperties();
                //File file = new File(p.getProperty("webdriver.path"));
                //System.setProperty(p.getProperty("webdriver.type"), file.getAbsolutePath());
                DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                //driver = new ChromeDriver();
                WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new java.net.URL("http://seleniumHubIp:4444/wd/hub"), capability);
                driver.get(p.getProperty("host.address")+APLICATION_CONTEXT);
                LoginPage login = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class);
                login.setUsuarioTextField(p.getProperty("usuario.selenium.login"));
                login.setSenhaPasswordField(p.getProperty("usuario.selenium.password"));
                home = login.submit();
        }
```

My mistake was writing the code to run local tests on a remote selenium node.

Answer (score 0):

You should have your parameters inside quotation marks in command line. Like this:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:/selenium/drivers/chromedriver.exe"
```